# Flow formula not evaluated after returning from previous screen

Tags: formula, visual-workflow, inputtext

I have a formula variable with my flow that uses values provided from the user on a screen component. When I proceed to the next screen, the flow uses this `fVariable` as the default value for a input text field. If the user goes to the previous screen and then returns back the text field value remains as the previous value.

I'm assuming this is because when the "previous" button was clicked the value that was on the field is now the actual value and therefore the "default" value is no longer being used. Is that correct? If so is there a way to determine if the default "formula" value should still be used instead?

Comment: i still have not wrapped my head around the expected behavior in navigating to previous, but i do know its [updating in summer20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_next_behavior_for_screen_components.htm) and should be better.  so i would first test in a summer20 sandbox to see if that resolves it.

Comment: @gorav Well that is good news, just need to wait 10 more days :P In my flow the next screen give the user a confirmation message with display text and if there is an issue there is a change they will go back to the previous screen.

Comment: @gorav To confirm, in my current sandbox I am on version Summer '20 Patch 9.3 (per https://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS36)

Comment: Confirmed that is definitely summer 20 running in that sandbox.  Does it work better?